# How to write ViewApi to check if data from user is in model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model User and every time user register singal sends verification code on email

And what do i need to write in my views.py to have ApiView to check if user write verification code that equals to verification code from model and if input code from user equals to code in db make `is_verified = True`

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),
                              null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone number'), max_length=30,
                             null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(_('verified'), default=False)

    verification_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=generate_code)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what style of DRF API views you have used, function or class.

For example, you can write a function view like [shown in docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view). Eg:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def confirm_user(request):
    if verification_code := request.data.get("verification_code"):
        user = User.objects.get(verification_code=verification_code)
        user.is_verified = True
        user.save()

    return Response({"message": "verified"})
```

The code sample can be improved with more error/data handling.